# mod_rewrite remove ?item=

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I would like to remove "?item=" from an URL.

So, from

```
domain.com/?item=2
```

To

```
domain.com/2
```

How to simply remove question mark, key and equal sign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert

- /?item=2

to

- /2

You can use this rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
#1) externally redirect the request "/?item=numbers" to "/numbers"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?item=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
#2) internally rewrite "/numbers" back to "/?item=numbers"
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /?item=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that kind of rewrite like;

```
[apache]
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/([0-9]{1})[/]?$ index.php?item=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually in your programming language you would write the final url you would like to see in the url bar, so `domain.com/2`, and then in your .htaccess file you would make this unrecognized address to become recognized by your program with transforming it to `domain.com/?item=2`.

This redirection would be done like:
`RewriteRule ^\d+$ index.php?item=$1 [L]`

**[EDIT]**

I know it's not fair if I edit my rule above - now I realize it's incomplete haha - so I change it here:

`RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?$ index.php?item=$1 [L]`

**The only thing I want to add to accepted answer is that you can replace `[0-9]+` with `\d+`.**